# How to use Verdana under Mac OS?

Tags: fonts, packages, mac

I am trying to use the Verdana font in LaTeX under Mac OS X.

I have found some packages, like `verdana` or `winfonts` but I can't get around to install them.

Can someone enlighten me of the best way to accomplish the Verdana font under Mac OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Here is an exemple :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}%déjà chargé par luatextra
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % to have the automatics ligatures of TeX
\setromanfont{Verdana}
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O} %font for sans-serif
%\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata} % font with fixe-chase
\begin{document}
test---TEST
\end{document}
```

You must compile it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
(with Texshop, simply write `%!TEX TS-program = lualatex` juste before the `\documentclass`)
and encode your document in UTF8 (again, with TexShop : `%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode`)

Comment: This worked. I was avoiding XeLaTeX